# How can I make this function minification safe?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, uglifyjs

I get that this is pretty much the convention to make a controller minification safe

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyController', ['myService', function (myService) {
  // Do something with myService
}]);
```

But my issue is that i have a function within the controller that is breaking the app. This below is the function

```js
function redirectWhenLoggedOut($q, $injector) {
                return {
                    responseError: function (rejection) {

                        var $state = $injector.get('$state');
                        var rejectionReasons =      ['token_not_provided', 'token_expired',
                            'token_absent', 'token_invalid'
                        ];
                        angular.forEach(rejectionReasons, function (value, key) {

                            if (rejection.data.error === value) {

                               
                                localStorage.removeItem('user');

                                
                                $state.go('main.login');
                            }
                        });

                        return $q.reject(rejection);
                    }

                }


            }
```

How do i refactor it in a way that will make it minification proof as well?

Comment: Maybe start with `redirectWhenLoggedOut.$inject = ['$q', '$injector']`. such that your method params wont be lost.

Comment: doing that seems to render redirectWhenLoggedOut as undefined

Answer (score 0):

This should work, move your two function variables into the controller.  If that doesn't work, you may need to grab a reference to 'this' in the main controller function first: `var vm = this;` and then use `vm.$q`.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyController', ['myService', '$q', '$injector', function (myService, $q, $injector) {
  // Do something with myService
  function redirectWhenLoggedOut() {
    return {
    responseError: function (rejection) {

        var $state = $injector.get('$state');
        var rejectionReasons =      ['token_not_provided', 'token_expired',
            'token_absent', 'token_invalid'
        ];
        angular.forEach(rejectionReasons, function (value, key) {
            if (rejection.data.error === value) {              
                localStorage.removeItem('user');                
                $state.go('main.login');
            }
        });

        return $q.reject(rejection);
  };
}]);
```